Excel VBA select/open and copy data from two or more workbooks
I'm hoping you could help me and point me in the right direction;
I'm currently working on a code that would help me to select and open to workbooks and copy the all the information in each workbook and paste into in the main workbook sheet called "Data".
I looking for the search and open file option instead of fixing the file folder location into the code so any user can search and select the workbook from different folders;
The current code is stopping when selecting the main workbook to activate and paste the copied data of the active woorkbook which is one of the two previously selected;
The code i'm trying:
Option Explicit

Sub opening_multiple_file()

Dim wb As ThisWorkbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear

    
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"

    If .Show = True Then
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)
            
        Next i
    End If
    End With
    
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    wb2.Activate
    wb2.Worksheets("Data").Range("D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wb.Activate
    wb.Worksheets("data").Range("D1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    wb.Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close
    
    Set wb3 = ActiveWorkbook
    wb3.Activate
    wb3.Worksheets("Data").Range("D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wb.Activate
    wb.Worksheets("data").Range("D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    wb.Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close
    


End Sub


What do you mean by I looking for the search and open file option instead of the file folder location option so any user can search and select the workbook?  The file dialog that appears has a Search documents text box allowing you to search for files.

Hi Darren,
Sorry if I was not clear, I'm new in VBA coding, what I meant is that I don't want to fix the folder and or file name into the code, since name and folder will be different based on the user

This code will copy the two selected ranges from the two workbooks into the target workbook horizontally aligned.
Option Explicit

Sub opening_multiple_file()

Dim wb As ThisWorkbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear

    
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"

    If .Show = True Then
        
            
       Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
       Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(2))

    End If
    End With
    
    wb2.Activate
    wb2.Worksheets("Data").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wb.Activate
    wb.Worksheets("Data").Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    wb3.Activate
    wb3.Worksheets("Data").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wb.Activate
    wb.Worksheets("Data").Select
    Range("D1").End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub

In this second code directly copy to the target workbook the required ranges. This avoid of switching between the workbooks.
Sub open_copy_multiple_file()

Dim wb As ThisWorkbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear

    
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"

    If .Show = True Then
        
            
       Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
       Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(2))

    End If
    End With
    
    wb2.Activate
    wb2.Worksheets("Data").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy wb.Worksheets("Data").Range("D1")
    'wb.Activate
    'wb.Worksheets("Data").Select
    'Range("D1").Activate
    'ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    wb3.Activate
    wb3.Worksheets("Data").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy wb.Worksheets("Data").Range("D1").End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1)
    'wb.Activate
    'wb.Worksheets("Data").Select
    'Range("D1").End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Select
    'ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub




This code might work for you.
It also gets rid of all that Select and Activate stuff - please, as a new coder get out of that habit as soon as possible.
How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA
Sub Test()

    'This will return the users MyDocuments folder as a string.
    'Or use any other method to return a folder as a string.
    'This can then be used in the SelectFile function to specify the start folder.
    'https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/wshshell-specialfolders.html
    Dim FolderToOpen As String
    FolderToOpen = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Specialfolders("MyDocuments")

    'Ask user to select files to import.
    Dim SelectedFiles As String
    
    'Uncomment the end of the next line to have the dialog open at the specified folder.
    SelectedFiles = SelectFile '(StartFolder:=FolderToOpen)
    
    
    'Split the returned paths into an array.
    Dim FilesToOpen As Variant
    FilesToOpen = Split(SelectedFiles, "|")
    
    Dim itm As Variant
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim MissingSheets As String
    'Look at each item in the workbook array.
    For Each itm In FilesToOpen
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=itm, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
        
        'Only continue if the workbook contains a sheet called "Data"
        If WorkSheetExists("Data", wrkBk) Then
            Set wrkSht = wrkBk.Worksheets("Data")
            Set rLastCell = LastCell(wrkSht)
            
            'Only continue if the last populated cell is >= column D.
            If rLastCell.Column >= 4 Then
                With wrkSht
                    .Range(.Cells(1, 4), rLastCell).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                End With
            End If
        Else
            MissingSheets = MissingSheets & wrkBk.Name & vbCrLf
        End If
        
        wrkBk.Close
    Next itm
    
    If MissingSheets <> "" Then MsgBox "These files did not contain a 'Data' sheet: " & vbCr & MissingSheets, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub

'Function for the FileDialog.
Public Function SelectFile(Optional StartFolder As String = "") As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Select data workbooks."
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .InitialFileName = StartFolder
        
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
        
        If .Show = True Then
            Dim itm As Variant
            Dim tmp As String
            For Each itm In .SelectedItems
                tmp = tmp & itm & "|"
            Next itm
            SelectFile = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)
        End If
    End With

End Function

'Function to check if the named worksheet exists within the named workbook.
Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wrkBk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    If wrkBk Is Nothing Then Set wrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = wrkBk.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

'Return the last cell containing data within the named worksheet.
Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range
    With wrkSht
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            Set LastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=.Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
        Else
            Set LastCell = .Cells(1, 1)
        End If
    End With
End Function

